# Initialise SimpleMessageListenerContainer as stopped

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-boot, spring-jms

Is there a way to initialise a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` as stopped?

i.e. I don't want to consume any JMS messages until later when a user will execute an action to start the JMS container

I've tried calling `.stop()` as soon as I create the bean... but it seems to be too early.

Calling stop/start later works fine but I don't want to risk processing any messages until the user is ready.

Comment: set `autoStartup` to `false`.

Comment: Derp! Should have read the javadoc more thoroughly. Thank you

Comment: Added an answer (a bit more extensive then the comment :) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html) implements the [`SmartLifecycle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) interface. This interface defines a method [`isAutoStartup`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html#isAutoStartup--). When this method returns `true` the component will automatically start.

Most beans implementing the `SmartLifecycle` interface also have a method `setAutoStartup` to allow for setting of this property. Setting it to `false` will disable auto start of the component.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    // Other Properties initialization
</bean>
```

Or in Java Config

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer smlc = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    smlc.setAutoStartup(false);
    ...
    return smlc;
}
```

At the moment it isn't possible to set this property using the jms namespace.